# Need assistance for installing .apk file

Tags: android

*I am trying to install a voice recognition app,that I builded ,on my device, the device is not supporting it, now I am trying to instal it on a LG Optimus 2x, I've updated this LG phone's OS to ICS using Cynogenmode, so no debugging options are getting displayed, can I directly copy the .apk file from the bin to LG phone? Would that work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note: If you install the APK directly do you phone, you have to enable that you can install applications from outside of the market in the settings of the phone. but then it should just work....

Answer (score 1):

you have to install app installer from android market. Then copy apk file to memory card.  Launch app installer, which will display apps from memory card and select, just install it.

another method 
attach .apk file as an email attachment, open that email using your devices, email client will show install button